# ACS ACR122 SDK Android Peer-to-Peer support?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, acr122

I am looking to connect the ACS ACR122 to an Android tablet via USB using their SDK.  This part works and I am able to read Mifare NFC cards.

The problem:
I am unable to read NFC smartphones like the Galaxy S3 or Nexus S when I tap against the ACR122.

When looking at what ACS provided it seems they left out of the Android SDK peer-to-peer communication support.

Does anyone know of a solution, workaround or alternative.  I am trying to enable my tablet to be able to read from an NFC smartphone.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime? I'm stuck with the same problem.